# Shell 'tr' command returns a new empty line

Tags: shell, csv, unix

I had a problem with trim command in Unix. I had a original.csv file saved from windows excel that I wanted to port to use in Unix. The content in original.csv saved from windows is like:

```
Func,Failing Cycle
rtg_generic_A_A1_N2_cb_TEST_1_sm32,859180
rtg_generic_A_A1_N3_cb_TEST_1_sm32,859180
rtg_generic_A_A3_N5_dw_cb_TEST_1_sm32,788581
```

I wanted to trim off the carriage return in it so I put command:

```
tr '\r\n' '\n' < original.csv >trimmed.csv
```

yet the content inside trimmed.csv looks like:

```
Func,Failing Cycle

rtg_generic_A_A1_N2_cb_TEST_1_sm32,859180

rtg_generic_A_A1_N3_cb_TEST_1_sm32,859180

rtg_generic_A_A3_N5_dw_cb_TEST_1_sm32,788581
```

It seems additional empty line is added in between. May I know why and how I can get rid of this empty line?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This command:

```
tr '\r\n' '\n'` < file
```

will translate each instance of `\r` into `\n` as `tr` translates character by character. This will make each line end with 2 `\n`.

To delete carriage returns, you can use this `tr` command:

```
tr -d '\r' < file
```

Comment: So it's not like substituting the entire '\r\n' with '\n'?

Comment: No it is not. Use `tr -d '\r' < file` to remove carriage return. `\n` is already there.

Comment: Thanks. I see the point. It's simply substituting '\r' to '\n'. Thus '\n\n' then I will see an empty line. But why it is still keeping that '\n' next to '\r'? Thanks

Comment: Yes exactly that is what is happening.

Comment: Thanks...I get your idea... it's substituting each lexcial in arg1 with arg2.... that's why it comes with 2 '\n'

Answer (score 1):

To convert line endings from Windows to Unix you can also use the [dos2unix](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dos2unix) command